# Send parameter from @extends layout into controller Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have question about extending layout with parameter.

```
@extends('layouts.app',[
                'page_lang' => 'jp',
                'canonical' => url()->current(),
                'body_class' => config('elpage.bodyclass.front_second').' '.config('elpage.bodyclass.front_second_about'),
                'repeat_desp_keyword' => true
            ]
        )
```

Is possible to get `'repeat_desp_keyword' => true` in `Controller`?
If possible, can you tell me how to control it?

Note: I want to get this parameter in all controllers.

Thank you so much.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible, because the action gets executed before the view. How do you determine the value of `repeat_desp_keyword`?

Comment: Hi @Dan Thank you. I want to get SEO from DB but second pages will use keyword and description same as home page so I want define which page use similar meta keys

Comment: Does it help to know you can use [`View::share()`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Contracts/View/Factory.html#method_share) to globally share a variable with your views? This way you can control and override it from your controllers if necessary.

Comment: @Dan That is good idea. I will try with your suggestion. thank you so much.

Comment: I can define share function to `Controller` 
`$seo = seotitle();
return view('index', ["seo" => $seo]);`

but I cannot add `AppServiceProvider.php`
`public function boot()
    {
        $seo = seotitle(); //error.
   }
}`;

Can you tell me why?

Comment: What's the error?